# How to block some of http user agent using php

Tags: php, user-agent

there have a way to block some of user agent via php script? Example on mod_security

```
SecFilterSelective HTTP_USER_AGENT "Agent Name 1"
SecFilterSelective HTTP_USER_AGENT "Agent Name 2"
SecFilterSelective HTTP_USER_AGENT "Agent Name 3"
```

Also we can block them using htaccess or robots.txt by example but I want in php. Any example code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I like @Nerdling's answer, but in case it's helpful, if you have a very long list of user agents that need to be blocked:

```
$badAgents = array('fooAgent','blahAgent', 'etcAgent');
foreach($badAgents as $agent) {
    if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],$agent) !== false) {
        die('Go away');
    }
}
```

Better yet:

```
$badAgents = array('fooAgent','blahAgent', 'etcAgent');
if(in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],$badAgents)) {
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Regardless, with anything above 2 user agents this would be the preferred method.

Comment: Yes.. Better yet working fine, just tested with http://chrispederick.com/work/user-agent-switcher/ thanks karim.

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid using regex for this as that will add a lot of resources just to decide to block a connection.  Instead, just check to see if the string is there with strpos()

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "Agent Name 1") !== false
 || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "Agent Name 2") !== false
 || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "Agent Name 3") !== false) {
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that using a regexp "will add a lot of resources"?

Comment: Because PHP's web site says so.

Comment: You should use strpos( $str ) !== false, since the substring could be positioned at index 0, and the test > 0 would fail. There's a note on the strpos() page specifically regarding type testing.