# How to Stop a CURL form spammer?

Tags: php, curl

We are using phpforms.net for one of our php webpages. And we are getting non-stop spammed with bs form submissions.

They are clearly using something much more complex then a bot to just auto fill out a form as they are able to bypass the maxlength html requirements and all javasript on the page. This [Auto fill and submit forms on external site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8741545/auto-fill-and-submit-forms-on-external-site)
shows a way to resend POST using CURL so I'm wondering if that is what I'm up against and how can I stop it?

Comment: Have you tried captcha?

Comment: Sadly that's one of the reasons captcha and recaptcha exists. The alternative is an AKISMET style system that looks at form submissions themselves and attempts to determine whether or not they are spam.

Comment: actually, constructing a POST request with a bot is the simple thing to do. Having a browser and auto-fill forms would be much more complex...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[reCaptha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) will save you! :^)
It looks great and its code is very easy to implement.

Comment: So reCaptch can stop CURL spam isn't it javascript based?

Comment: You should read about [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) test. In short its idea that no request will be accepted until it will pass captcha test. There is no difference how this request was made - by form submitting, by CURL or by direct mind message from Mars: No legs - no candies.

Answer (score 2):

I recently created a class to prevent spam without the use of Captha.
It does 3 things.

**Honey pots:** A field that is `display:none`. Spam bots can see it and will fill it, but your legit User will not. If it has any value at all, then the form is invalid.

**Spinner:** A random string created and stored in a session before rendering the form, then posted in a `type="hidden"` input. If the string different after submitting, then the form in invalid.

**Random field names:** A random string stored in a session for each field name (on every form request)

After implementing this on a form, it went from 100+ spams per day to none.

I remember reading an article on these, i'll try look for it.

Comment: Your "spinner" and "random field names", based on sessions, doesn't look good. If the user opens by mistake the same link in a new tab and then close it, then the form will be invalid.

Comment: Careful with honey pots, some browsers auto-fill fields. Use a unique field name, and do not put it above any `type="password"` fields or it might get filled with a saved username.

Answer (score 1):

According to [PHPForms Features](http://phpforms.net/v2/features.html) they offer reCATPCHA. This is actually why captcha was invented - because of spam bots abusing html forms.

The method of captcha is to attempt to make it difficult for a bot to submit a form without human intervention. The alternative is after-submission heuristic process like [Akismet](http://akismet.com/) which tries to determine spam by looking at the submitted text itself.

So basically you either make it slightly harder to submit your forms by insisting on captcha validity, or you just deal with the spam.

Answer (score 1):

This may/may not help you, but I recently ran into a spam problem myself. I tried this solution and it has completely fixed the spam problem. **There is no need to use Captcha with this method:**

In your form, create a new input field and hide it with `display: none` in your CSS. This field is the spam trap. Real users cannot see this field, but **spam bots can**. Therefore, on the back end, if the `$_POST` data from this hidden field contains *anything at all*, then the submission is spam, and you can handle it as such.

Read more about it [here](http://www.wilhelser.com/2012/04/stop-bot-submitted-form-spam/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are just dealing with one particular bot you can probably block that user agent.

Example from [How to block some of http user agent using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357983/how-to-block-some-of-http-user-agent-using-php)

```
$badAgents = array('fooAgent','blahAgent', 'etcAgent');
if(in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],$badAgents)) {
    exit();
}
```

Or for just general curl:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'curl') !== false)
    exit;
```

In many cases they aren't really attacks so much as the author not realizing that their code is stuck on your site. If it does turn out to be some kind of malicious activity, then yes, you will need a captcha.

Comment: you can easily fake `HTTP_USER_AGENT`

Comment: @Baba Yes. Hence why if it is malicious this won't work. However, in practice the bots do not have an active human mind behind them and so can be easily stopped with simpler methods like this.

Answer (score 0):

Validation when working with a server side code should be handled server side. JavaScript will do nothing if the client in question doesn't interact with JavaScript.

Validate server side, even if you use a captcha you should ALWAYS validate information on the server.
use either a captcha system or text analysis system,or both,  such as [reCaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) or [mollom](http://mollom.com/) or [akismet](http://akismet.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I do a couple things. I actually use reCaptcha and then have a blank text field which I hide with jQuery becasue some bots can actually read some CSS and won't fill in the field if the display: none is attached to it.

As always, you should do some backend processing as well. In addition to verifying the lameCaptcha field I just said, if you have a required field on the front end use a trim() and verify that it actually has a value. If there is no value then don't actually process the form.